# Calling android shell app native function from trusted web activity(PWA)

Tags: javascript, java, android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I am trying to call android shell app native function from a trusted web activity in a PWA.

I know that we can do this for webviews using @JavascriptInterface notation, but couldn't find any information if same can be done for trusted web activity as well.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Trusted Web Activities currently don't have an API that is analog to WebView's [`addJavaScriptInterface()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)). It's only possible to pass parameters when starting the activity, via [query parameters](https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity/query-parameters) or [custom headers](https://developers.google.com/web/android/custom-tabs/headers). I do recommend filing an issue at https://crbug.com/ describing the use-case you'd like to use this API for, so the team can investigate providing an API for that.